# Unused expression error in typescript using tslint

Tags: typescript, lint, tslint

I am getting a tslint error and am not sure how to solve it.

I want to store a value in the sessionStorage, which is working, but my linter is telling me I'm doing something wrong.

Am I supposed to return a value?

```
 import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { WindowService } from './window.service';

 @Injectable()
 export class SessionStorageService {

  constructor(
     @Inject(WindowService) private window: Window) {
  }

  public get(key: string): void {
     window.sessionStorage.getItem[key]; // THIS IS LINE 12
  }

  public save(key: string, value: any): void {
     window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
}
```

The error:

> ERROR: client/src/services/session-storage.service.ts[12, 9]: unused 
>   expression, expected an assignment or function call

Comment: `getItem[key]` with brackets? Should it be using parentheses? EG: `getItem(key)`?

Comment: Also, what's the point of getting something from the storage, and do nothing with it?

Comment: @CRice I believe it needs to use parentheses?

Comment: @JBNizet right, I need to return it! But in terms of code, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, yes, as CRice told you already. Why don't you consult the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage